# Dilemma with the classification theorem of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We know that if $H < G$ , $G$ commutative, and $G/H \cong \hat H < G$, then $ G \cong H \oplus \hat H$. Then on the basis of this I could write $Z_4 \cong Z_2 \oplus Z_2 $ but we know that $Z_4 \ncong Z_2 \oplus Z_2$ then where am i wrong?This example shows that the above lemma is not always true! Please explain this.

Comment: You have answered your question yourself. It is **not** true that if $G$ is abelian and $G/H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $K$ of $G$ then $G\simeq H\oplus K$! This is not true in general for a group $G$. For example $S_3$ has a normal subgroup $A_3=C_3$ and $S_3/A_3\simeq C_2$ which is a subgroup of $S_3$ but $S_3\not\simeq A_3\times C_2$ since the latter group is abelian and $S_3$ is not.

Comment: yeah, i got it thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question, congratulations!

In general the property that would guarantee that an abelian group can be decomposed as a direct sum (and in fact the two properties are equivalent) is the fact that $0 \to H \to G \to G/H \to 0$ is such that there exists a map $\phi: G/H \to G$ such that $\pi \circ \phi = Id_{G/H}$, where $\pi: G \to G/H$ is projection.

This is what is being used in the classification theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, which I believe is what you are referring to. In general it is called the splitting lemma.

Cheers